# Must an alpha=0.01 be used to interpret significance of parametric terms in a GAM?

Tags: statistical-significance, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, parametric

I have fit a time-series count HGAM with environmental covariates as parametric terms and year as a site-varying smooth term. I am wondering if I need to use an alpha threshold of 0.01 to interpret significant p values for the parametric terms, or is a 0.05 threshold appropriate?

Thank you for any help

Comment: The choice of $\alpha$ is yours, though you should make it before you do your analysis.  How worried are you about Type I errors (erroneous rejection of the null hypothesis, i.e. false positives)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Henry; I'm not particularly worried about Type I errors, but I know that when interpreting significance of smooth terms in GAMs, an alpha=0.01 is typically used. I'm not sure if this convention also applies to parametric terms in the model though.